# Javascript function called, but result not fully returned

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, meteor

I am new to Meteor and Node.js, there for my problem might just be a banality for those more skilled.

I am writing a script, that should return time in +30 minute in the future, in this format: `11.12.16 20:05` However, if I try to run my function, nothing seems to be happening and I get no errors in console or from server.

This is my html:

```
<body>

    <header>DPPZ</header>

    {{> price24}}
    {{> price32}}

    <div id="newWindow" style="display: none;">
        <p id="time"></p>
    </div>

</body>

<template name="price24">
    <div class="container24">
        <button id="container24" onclick="ticket24()">24Kč</button>
        <p>(30 minut)</p>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="price32">
    <div class="container32">
        <button id="container32" onclick="ticket32()">32Kč</button>
        <p>(90 minut)</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here is my JS:

```
function ticket24(){
    document.getElementById("newWindow").style.display = "block";

    var d = new Date();
    var den = d.getDate();
    var mesic = d.getMonth();
    var rok = d.getFullYear();
    var hodina = d.getUTCHours();
    var minuta = d.getUTCMinutes();

    switch(mesic){
        case(0):
            mesic = 1;
        case(1):
            mesic = 2;
        case(2):
            mesic = 3;
        case(3):
            mesic = 4;
        case(4):
            mesic = 5;
        case(5):
            mesic = 6;
        case(6):
            mesic = 7;
        case(7):
            mesic = 8;
        case(8):
            mesic = 9;
        case(9):
            mesic = 10;
        case(10):
            mesic = 11;
        case(11):
            mesic = 12;
    }

    function novaMinuta(hodiny, minuty){
        switch(minuta){
          case(0):
              minuta = "00";
          case(1):
              minuta = "01";
          case(2):
              minuta = "02";
          case(3):
              minuta = "03";
          case(4):
              minuta = "04";
          case(5):
              minuta = "05";
          case(6):
              minuta = "06";
          case(7):
              minuta = "07";
          case(8):
              minuta = "08";
          case(9):
              minuta = "09";
          default: 
              minuta = minuta;
       }

        if (10 <= Number(minuta) >= 29){
            return Number(hodina + 1)+ ":" + Number(minuta) + 30;
        }
        else if (Number(minuta) == 30){
            return Number(hodina + 2) + ":" + "00";
        }
        else if (Number(minuta) > 30){
            return Number(hodina + 2) + ":" + Number(minuta) - 30;
        }
    }
    rok = rok.toString().replace("20", "");


    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = den + "." + mesic + "." + rok +
    " " + novaMinuta(hodina, minuta);

    document.getElementById("newWindow").style.display = "block";


}
```

The `document.getElementById("newWindow").style.display = "block";` works, but the rest of the code 'prints' nothing.

Comment: `10 <= Number(minuta) >= 29` doesn't behave like you're probably expecting. `Number(minuta)` isn't shared by both side. It's understood instead as `(10 <= Number(minuta)) >= 29` – meaning `true >= 29` or `false >= 29`, ultimately. It should be `10 <= Number(minuta) && Number(minuta) >= 29`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `break` for each `case`:

```
switch(mesic){
        case(0):
            mesic = 1;
            break;
        case(1):
            mesic = 2;
            break;
        ...
```